# Gather Viewers IP

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, ip, visitor-statistic

I want to know how to get the IP address of visitors to my site. I will then put this into an SQL table that will count how many times they visit. I know PHP, JavaScript, HTML, and MySQL so I just need to know what the code for getting a viewer's IP is, I can code the rest myself.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Look at some Tracing programms like Google Adsense (Evil) or Piwik (OpenSource and local!). They do that and even more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the user's IP address by accessing the $_SERVER array:

```
 echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Dude I did google and all I got was COME TO OUR SITE AND WE"LL DO IT FOR YOU! Thanks for the down vote. As you can see in the comment to my original post, someone already suggested that I just let someone else do it.

Comment: @ChapmIndustries: what makes you think this answerer downvoted you? There's a lot of users on this site. A person answering your question doesn't generally also downvote it.

Comment: I appologize, the three down votes and then the comment about a simple search would lead me to believe he was a culprit in the downvote. Sorry I jumped to conclusions. Thanks for the speedy reply anyways Wayne Whitty!

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

Just look in the `$_SERVER` variable.

That should have all the info you need.